# Drag content in and out of a jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to drag stuff out of a jQuery UI dialog and drop it onto the page? I'm using html() function to move data between the dialog and the page, but it would be cool to have the drag and drop effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Make the content of the jQuery UI dialog [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and the place where you want to drop it [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/).